# Dynamically find last row in apex:dataTable

Tags: visualforce

How can I dynamically find the last row of a dataset in `apex:dataTable`?  My goal is to set the styleClass of the last row (non-footer) to 'last'...

I have an `apex:variable` that tracks the row number and I was thinking about comparing this to the query.size property, but wasn't sure exactly how to do this...

```
<apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!1}"/>
<apex:dataTable value="{!displayResults}" var="result" styleClass="list" rowClasses="dataRow odd,dataRow even" headerClass="headerRow">
    <apex:column style="{!IF(rowNum == displayResults.size, 'last', '')}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!FLOOR(rowNum)}"/>
        <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="field">
        <apex:column styleClass="dataCell" onmousemove="this.parentNode.classList.add('highlight')" onmouseout="this.parentNode.classList.remove('highlight')">
            <apex:facet name="header">{!mapFieldLabel[field]}</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!result[field]}" rendered="{!field != 'Name'}" />
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!result['Id']}" rendered="{!field == 'Name'}">
                <apex:outputField value="{!result[field]}" />
            </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:dataTable>
```

In this example, I'd like to have the final row (row 7) with a styleClass="last"...

[image: dataTable example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another mechanism which can be used if you need more than the CSS selector that Matt supplied for last-child would be to use script in the page to add a class of `last` to the className attribute on the last row in the table body element.

The script targets the first `tbody` element in the table hierarchy and appends the string `last` to the end of the existing `className` attribute.

```
<apex:page controller="YourController">
    <apex:dataTable id="accountTable" value="{!Accounts}" var="a" styleClass="list" rowClasses="dataRow odd,dataRow even" headerClass="headerRow">
        <apex:column value="{!a.Id}" />
        <apex:column value="{!a.Name}" />
    </apex:dataTable>
    <script>
        (function(tableId) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
            if (table) {
                var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
                tbody.rows[tbody.rows.length - 1].className += ' last';
            }
        })('{!$Component.accountTable}');
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Relevant Mozilla documentation about targeting the elements of an HTML Table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement

Comment: I did need to modify the $Component reference to $Component.thePage:accountTable and add id="thePage" to the apex:page tag to make this work.  Thank you!  I like the non-css (kind of) hack!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach to this problem -- use an inner class in your Controller for displayResults. The inner class represents one row and includes a method that can return the styleclass for the 1st...n-1st rows versus the nth row.

Alternatively, you can have the inner class simply have a boolean method `getIsLastRow()` and let the VF page use an `{!IF (result.isLastRow,'lastStyleclass','notLastStyleclass')}` to select the styleclass if you want to keep styleclass names out of the controller.

This eliminates the `apex:variable` component and can be extended to provide all sorts of hints to the VF page about how to conditionally render fields or rows.

```
// Within your controller

 public List<DisplayResult> displayResults {get; private set;}
 displayResults = new List<DisplayResults> ();
 for (some loop vbl)  // populate the inner class, one row per whatever you are trying to display
   displayResults.add(new DisplayResult(this,theData); // 'theData' is however you want to pass name, stage, freezedate - if all in the same SObject, then theData is the sObject from the for loop

  // Inner class to manage results and dynamically set style
  public DisplayResult class {
   Integer rowNum;
   MyController myCtlr;
 // other fields to display go here

  public DisplayResult(MyController myCtlr, someType theData) {  // constructor
   this.rowNum = myCtlr.displayResults.size() + 1;
   this.myCtlr = myCtlr;
   // remember the other data you need
  }
 public String getStyle() {
   return this.rowNum == this.myCtlr.displayResults.size() ? 'lastStyleClass' : 'notlastStyleClass';
 }      
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried doing the styling using CSS selectors rather than a class?

I think `table.list tr:last-child` might be what you're looking for:

```
/* .last */
table.list tr:last-child
{
  color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers since this one worked as well...